# android cancel multiple alarms with custom uri

Tags: java, android

I created some alarms in my service which service sometimes restarts. I would like to cancel these alarms when my service restarts.
I set multiple alarms with multiple action type and with custom URIs like this (I need custom URIs for multiple alarms for the same action):

```
for(..) {
String id = "id:"+i;
intent = new Intent(AlarmReceiver.MY_ALARM, Uri.parse(id), context, AlarmReceiver.class);
}
```

how could I cancel all of the alarms? 
AlarmManager.cancel() need to know all Action and URI pair for filtering (maybe I'm wrong)
I tried using PendingIntent's requestCode for create multiple alarm for the same Action but after the first alarm fired AlarmReceiver didn't give me back the Intent's extras.

I think I have to store persistent details about what alarms I set before. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to persist the alarms that you are adding. And then cancel them one-by-one.